# Pandas: How to preserve rows with index and empty values in pivot_table for appending to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have been pulling out my hair (if I'd had any left) getting the following to work for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1={'TS':['2021-07-17 00:05:00', '2021-07-17 00:05:00', '2021-07-17 00:10:00', '2021-07-17 00:15:00', '2021-07-17 00:20:00'],
    'CM':['C1','C1','C2','C3','C4'],
    'ST':['S1','S1','S2','S2','S3']}

d2={'TS':['2021-07-18 00:05:00', '2021-07-18 00:10:00', '2021-07-18 00:16:00', '2021-07-18 00:21:00','2021-07-18 00:27:00'],
   'CM':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
   'ST':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

dtot = pd.DataFrame()
df1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2)

d1p = pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['TS'], values=['CM'], columns=['ST'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0, dropna=False)
d2p = pd.pivot_table(df2, index=['TS'], values=['CM'], columns=['ST'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0, dropna=False)

dtot = dtot.append(d1p)
dtot = dtot.append(d2p)
```

This will result in:

```
                    CM      
ST                  S1 S2 S3
TS                          
2021-07-17 00:05:00  2  0  0
2021-07-17 00:10:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:15:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:20:00  0  0  1
```

So rows of df2 are all ignored (d2p will be an empty dataframe).

What I would like to have is:

```
                    CM      
ST                  S1 S2 S3
TS                          
2021-07-17 00:05:00  2  0  0
2021-07-17 00:10:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:15:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:20:00  0  0  1                      
2021-07-18 00:05:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:10:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:16:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:21:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:27:00  0  0  0
```

So I need to preserve the timestamps and get "zero" values in d2p.
The issue is of course that the possible values (as occurences S1,S2,S3) are absent for categorizing the pivot d2p.

Still, how can I achieve the end result?

Answer (score 0):

Your d2p is empty due to the NaN values.

You can fix that by adding a fillna before the pivot:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2).fillna(0)
```

Then the pivot get mixed up with the 0 value, so skip the last column of the dtot, and fillna again to remove NaNs and convert to int if you do not want the 0.0.

```
dtot.iloc[:,:-1].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                    CM      
ST                  S1 S2 S3
TS                          
2021-07-17 00:05:00  2  0  0
2021-07-17 00:10:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:15:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:20:00  0  0  1
2021-07-18 00:05:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:10:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:16:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:21:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:27:00  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you only `pivot_table` dataframe with actual observed values, and then create a **combined index** of timestamps and `.reindex` it with those values to get your desired output.

This has the advantage of being less computationally intensive (no point in running a `pivot_table` call on a table we know with no valid observations).

```
timestamps = df1["TS"].append(df2["TS"]).unique()

new_df = (
    df1.pivot_table(
        index=['TS'], 
        values=['CM'], 
        columns=['ST'], 
        aggfunc=len, 
        fill_value=0, 
        dropna=False
    )
    .reindex(timestamps, fill_value=0)
)

print(new_df)
                    CM      
ST                  S1 S2 S3
TS                          
2021-07-17 00:05:00  2  0  0
2021-07-17 00:10:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:15:00  0  1  0
2021-07-17 00:20:00  0  0  1
2021-07-18 00:05:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:10:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:16:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:21:00  0  0  0
2021-07-18 00:27:00  0  0  0
```